# Windows: UTF-16BE to UTF-8

Tags: c++, windows, unicode

Can anybody tell me the secret undocumented black magic incantations required to force Windows to process *big endian* UTF-16?

A simple call to `WideCharToMultiByte()` is all that is needed to convert UTF-16LE to UTF-8. But how do I make this work for UTF-16BE? I've searched and searched and searched and I can't find any information about this. (I can't possibly be the first human on Earth to need to do this...)

Obviously big endian numbers are not native to the Intel platform, but surely Windows must have an API for dealing with this somewhere.

Comment: I don't think it does (as it's not a supported encoding). Just swap the endieness (is that a word) yourself and then call `WideCharToMultiByte`

Comment: Richard is right and the way to go. Windows expects the input to be in LE. Prepare your data Windows wants and get what you need. @RichardCritten: Probably worth as an answer.

Comment: _swab() gets the job done.  A posix function, hehe.

Comment: @HansPassant This is definitively the answer :). Except that swab is the posix function, and _swab is the microsft's version ^^.

Comment: But... if you have a file encoded in UTF-16BE with a BOM, programs such as Notepad load it just fine. Are you really saying that every single program that needs to deal with UTF-16BE reimplements it independently?

Comment: dude, it's literally one line of code to convert it. Detection is done with IsTextUnicode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Obviously big endian numbers are not native to the Intel platform, but surely Windows must have an API for dealing with this somewhere.

Nope.  It only supports UTF-16LE.  To handle UTF-16BE, you have to convert to UTF-16LE first by swapping the bytes of each UTF-16 codeunit.

You should consider using a dedicated Unicode library, such as [ICONV](https://www.gnu.org/software/libiconv/) or [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/).  Both support UTF-8, UTF-16LE, and UTF-16BE.

If you are using C++11, you can alternatively use its built-in [`std::codecvt_utf8_utf16`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_utf8_utf16) facet for converting between UTF-8 and UTF-16 LE/BE.  You can use the [`std::wstring_convert()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/wstring_convert) or [`std::wbuffer_convert()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/wbuffer_convert) function to perform the actual conversions.